# Ruby Array group_by key with multiple values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashtable

I have a Ruby Array:

```
[
    {tags: [1,2]},
    {tags: [1,3]},
    {tags: [1,4]},
    {tags: [2,4]},
    {tags: [2,5]}
]
```

I need to group the objects by their tags:

```
{
    1: [{tags: [1,2]}, {tags: [1,3]}, {tags: [1,4]}],
    2: [{tags: [1,2]}, {tags: [2,4]}, {tags: [2,5]}],
    3: [{tags: [1,3]}],
    4: [{tags: [1,4]}, {tags: [2,4]}],
    5: [{tags: [2,5]}]
}
```

Is there a magic Ruby Way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: @MarkThomas The question is in the title.  Given a Ruby Array of Hash elements, I want to index those elements by the values within an Array property of each Hash. It's harder to describe in words than it is to show you the code.  Hence my terse question with a focus on code.

Comment: @MarkThomas, This question is akin to: "what's the next number in the sequence 3, 9, 18, 30, 45?" I couldn't figure out the question until I read the answers. It appears that if `i` satisfies `h[:tags].include?[i] => true` for at least one of the five hashes `h`, then `i` is a key in the returned hash, and its value is an array of all the hashes `h` for which `h[:tags].include?[i] => true`. (The next element in the sequence is give by `3(n+n^2)/2`.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I thought the next element in the sequence was given by adding 3*n to the previous number in the sequence.  I also thought that `Ruby Array` and `group_by` were big enough clues to figure out what I was trying to do here.  And apparently they were...  I'm sorry to frustrate and/or confuse you.  I will try to consider a broader audience in future questions.

Comment: Whether readers understand a question is an empirical question. Here, some did, but I didn't until I looked at the answers.  I very much like "here's my input and expected output" questions, but sometimes a bit more is needed. In any event, I figured it out in the end and put up my earlier comment merely to help any others who might be struggling as I was. Downvote was not mine.

Comment: Instead of *only* putting the question in the title, also restate it in the body of the question. Also, I see no code, only definition for a hash, but nothing that could possibly manipulate it or create it. We need to know what you've written to try to solve this yourself. Stack Overflow isn't a "write code for me" service, it's a "I need help with code I wrote" service.

Comment: @theTinMan According to the homepage, Stack Overflow is "a question and answer site", of which you're doing neither.

Comment: [so] is a community maintained/moderated site, with a goal of becoming a Wikipedia-like compendium of programming problems and solutions. Accordingly, there are strongly encouraged standards for questions that, when followed, help us answer questions, and others who are searching for similar answers find those questions. As someone who's been around SO a little while I am aware of those things and trying to help you accomplish that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
tags = [
  {tags: [1,2]},
  {tags: [1,3]},
  {tags: [1,4]},
  {tags: [2,4]},
  {tags: [2,5]}
]
tags.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |h, result|
  h[:tags].each { |n| result[n] << h }
}
# => {1=>[{:tags=>[1, 2]}, {:tags=>[1, 3]}, {:tags=>[1, 4]}],
#     2=>[{:tags=>[1, 2]}, {:tags=>[2, 4]}, {:tags=>[2, 5]}],
#     3=>[{:tags=>[1, 3]}],
#     4=>[{:tags=>[1, 4]}, {:tags=>[2, 4]}],
#     5=>[{:tags=>[2, 5]}]}
```

Comment: Good answer and kudos for figuring out what was being asked.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
array = [{tags: [1,2]}, {tags: [1,3]}, {tags: [1,4]}, {tags: [2,4]}, {tags: [2,5]}]

result = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

array.each do |tags|
  tags[:tags].each { |tag| result[tag] << tags }
end

puts result
#=> {1=>[{:tags=>[1, 2]}, {:tags=>[1, 3]}, {:tags=>[1, 4]}], 
#    2=>[{:tags=>[1, 2]}, {:tags=>[2, 4]}, {:tags=>[2, 5]}], 
#    3=>[{:tags=>[1, 3]}], 
#    4=>[{:tags=>[1, 4]}, {:tags=>[2, 4]}], 
#    5=>[{:tags=>[2, 5]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. This is similar to what I came up with on my own, but your passing the block to `Hash.new` is an elegant touch.

Comment: You must have also figured out the question too, considering that your answer followed so closely on the heels of falsetru's. +1 for that alone, but good answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
tags.each_with_object({}) {|g,h| g.values.flatten.each {|i| (h[i]||=[]) << g}}
  #=> {1=>[{:tags=>[1, 2]}, {:tags=>[1, 3]}, {:tags=>[1, 4]}], 
  #    2=>[{:tags=>[1, 2]}, {:tags=>[2, 4]}, {:tags=>[2, 5]}],
  #    3=>[{:tags=>[1, 3]}],
  #    4=>[{:tags=>[1, 4]}, {:tags=>[2, 4]}],
  #    5=>[{:tags=>[2, 5]}]}
```